# uitableview scroll event stepper exchange

Tags: swift

I have a tableview and stepper.
stepper is touched, random stepper values is changing when tableview is moved.how do i prevent it. Thanks

Comment: Please, provide more information, some code part

Comment: I have added code..do you have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Code

UIViewController

```
 import UIKit

 class ViewController:UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{


@IBOutlet weak var tablee: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "test", for: indexPath) as! TesttViewCell

      return cell
}
}
```

TesttViewCell

```
import UIKit

class TesttViewCell: UITableViewCell {



@IBOutlet weak var adet: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet weak var lblTest: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@IBAction func changee(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    lblTest.text = String(sender.value)
}
}
```